# Removing commited files from older commit that have been deleted locally

Tags: git, github

I've managed to commit some files incidentally in commit `A001`. Those files are quite big (around 100MB each). After noticing my mistake, In next commit, I've deleted those files with `rm` command, and commited those changes to commit `A002`. I've thought that this solved my problem and continued developing. After few commits, let's say commit `A005` I've tried to push everything on remote (Large files have been deleted, but they're still commited in commit `A001`), push fails with following message:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
...
...

 ! [remote rejected] melodic-dev -> melodic-dev (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Which is okay, because large files still exist in commit `A001`.

How can I do following:

- Go back to commit `A001`, unstage those large files and recreate commit `A001` without those large files that have been removed, do same to commit `A002`
- Recreate all following commits `A003`-`A005`as they were on tip of the recreated `A001_edited-A002_edited` commits without those large files
- Push corrected `A001-A005` commits to remote branch

I would need something like: Create new branch that has all commits `NEW_BRANCH:A001-A005`. In that branch, I would like to remove some files from commit `A001`, therefore i would have `NEW_BRANCH: A001_edited` commit, and I would like to merge `OLD_BRANCH:A001-A002-A003-A004-A005` with `NEW_BRANCH: A001_edited-A002_edited` so that I have following: `OLD_BRANCH: A001_edited-A002_edited-A003-A004-A005`

A001_edited = A001 without commiting (revert `git add Large files`) those large files
A002_edited = A002 without removing (revert `git rm Large files`) those large files

In two successive commits somewhere in history, I want to remove some staged/unstaged files and keep everything else the same.

I've tried some stuff, but without success.
I hope I've clarified my problem enough, if not let me know :)

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed with a powerful and scary approach called rebasing! :) Here's one way:

1. Run `git rebase -i --root`. This will open an editor listing all commits all the way from A001 to your latest one.
2. In that file, change the word "pick" in front of A001 to "edit". Save the file and close the editor.
3. Git will rewind you to the moment after you made A001 (where you added the big files by mistake). Run `git rm --cached bigfile1 bigfile2` to remove them from the index, then run `git commit --amend` to fix commit A001 to not contain them.
4. Run `git rebase --continue`. This will reapply all commits after that on top of the commit you changed. A002 should now only contain the changes you made other than removing the files. No commit should contain the big files anymore.

Hope that works for you, let me know if you encounter any problems!

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I've completely forgot about `git rebase` command. I've managed to remove those files but I've had minor mental breakdown during merging those changes. What I've done? 
First I've run following command, and rebased to `A001`, removed staged bigfiles, 
Then I've used `git commit --ammend` and `git rebase --continue`, same for `A002`. Commited everything and pushed on remote. Push failed because branches had unrelated history. I've managed to push it with `--allow unrelated histories` flag.

Comment: My remote now looks like following: 
`Everything before A001` - `Everything before A001 - A001_edited - A002_edited - A003 - A004 - A005`. Rebase solved my problem, but from my perspective, that's quite complicated and not ideal. Although, maybe it's my insufficient git knowledge. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to use `rebase` as suggested by [blinry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248734/blinry) but without `git rm --cached bigfile1 bigfile2`.

I would use `git rm --cached bigfile1 bigfile2` if I haven't already done so
with `A002` commit.

To clarify, I've added accidentaly some big files to `A001` and
removed them in commit `A002` which disabled me from pushing on remote branch. I've simply used interactive rebasing and squashed commit `A002` into `A001`:
as follows:

```
pick A005 
pick A004 
pick A003
squash A002
pick A001
```

`Squash` command "merges" choosen commit with previous one, in this case it "merged" removal of big files with addition of big files and some code changes, which resulted with wanted code changes and without big files, and clean git history (`Everything before A001` - `A001_without_big_files` -`A003`-`A004`-`A005`)

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Cool that this worked for you! :) Yeah, that seems like a perfect opportunity for squashing!